# How to get current URL for chrome current version in C++

Tags: c++, google-chrome, url, hwnd, iaccessible

i want to get URL from Google Chrome using the MSAA apis, i already found this on StackOverflow but i want to replicate this behaviour =>[How to get current URL for chrome current version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010017/how-to-get-current-url-for-chrome-current-version) , without using **AccessibleObjectFromEvent** but with **AccessibleObjectFromWindow**. 
But after these lines:

```
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd_addr_bar, OBJID_CLIENT, IID_IAccessible, (void **)&ac);



    if ((hr == S_OK ) && (ac!=NULL)){
        tagVARIANT state;
        VariantInit(&state);
        BSTR szAddressBox = NULL;
        HRESULT hr1 = ac->get_accValue(varchild, &szAddressBox);

    }
```

szAddressBox is empty. Where am i wrong?