# How to retrieve URL from a browser with UIautomation and plain C

Tags: c, com, ui-automation

I want to obtain the URL of the browser Internet Explorer. I found the following code ([Get active Tab URL in Chrome with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504300/get-active-tab-url-in-chrome-with-c)) in C++ and I am trying to convert it to plain C.

```
IUIAutomationCondition *pCondition = NULL;
VARIANT url;
VARIANT varProp;
varProp.vt = VT_I4;
varProp.lVal = UIA_EditControlTypeId;
hr = IUIAutomation_CreatePropertyCondition(pAutomation,UIA_ControlTypePropertyId,varProp,&pCondition);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
  hr = IUIAutomationElement_FindFirst(pNode,TreeScope_Descendants,pCondition,&urlBar);
  if(urlBar!= NULL){
    IUIAutomationElement_GetCurrentPropertyValue(urlBar,UIA_ValueValuePropertyId,&url);
    MessageBox(0, url.bstrVal, L"success", 0);
  }
}
IUnknown_Release(pCondition);
```

This code prints the text URL "h" in the message box when I want to retrieve the value from the browser and the value should be [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com). I do not know what I am doing incorrectly. I really appreciate if someone could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The variable url.bstrVal is BSTR, then I should use MessageBoxW. With MessageBox, the code was printing only the first letter of the url. With MessageBoxW, I could print the whole URL.

Comment: Or, make your project a Unicode project so that MessageBox maps to MessageBoxW. In fact, that is what you should do.